# Why the rest of the value of i in loop are not printed?

Tags: python-3.x

For the following code:

```
middle = ['d', 'e', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'b'] 
print(middle)
flag=False
k=0
i=0
while i < (len(middle)-1):
    
    print(i,end=" ")
    if middle[i]==middle[i+1]:
        k=i
        flag=True
        ele=middle[i]
        i+=1
        #print(i)
    elif middle[i]!=middle[i+1] and flag==True:
        while(ele in middle[:k+1]):
            middle.remove(ele)
        i+=1
        flag=False
        #print(i)
    else:
        #print(i)
        i+=1
    print(i)
            
    #print(len(middle)-1)
        
print(middle)
```

The output is :

```
['d', 'e', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'b']                                                                           
0 1                                                                                                                     
1 2                                                                                                                     
2 3                                                                                                                     
3 4                                                                                                                     
4 5                                                                                                                     
['d', 'e', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'b']
```

I am wondering why the rest of the values of i are not getting printed.
Can someone please explain this.

Comment: What did you expect to get instead? The loop stops when `i` becomes larger than `len(middle)`. You should consider that the condition is reevaluated after every iteration, and you modify the length of `middle` in the loop.

Comment: Read this to learn how to solve problems like this yourself: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thank you for sharing this article, it was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is the `while` is check at *every* loop. Because you remove element from your list, the `len` goes smaller.

If you want the condition to remain the same, simply assign a variable to its original length just before the start of the loop:

```
length_ = len(middle)
while i < length_ - 1:
    ...
```

Was this helpful for you? Any questions?

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this will give an error                                                        `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I apologize if my answer didn't fit to your problem, I tried to answer your question as strictly as possible. However, it would be a pleasure to give an answer appropriate for your problem. To do so, can you explain a little bit deeper (with an *edit* in your original post) what you aimed to do and why it didn't work.